# Days calculation is not given correct days

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to calculate days based on two dates but it's given incorrect count of days.

I have 2 variables

`$date=$date[1];` **Is coming from Database**
`$now =date('d/m/Y')`; Current date

`$date` variable value is(comes from db) `05/03/2019`

I used following script for count days based on two dates but its return 120 days.

**Method 1**

```
$date=$date[1]; `Is coming from Database`
$now =date('d/m/Y');

$date1 = new DateTime($now);
$date2 = new DateTime($date);
$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

**Method 2**

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($now);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date);

$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo 'Difference: '.$difference->y.' years, ' 
                   .$difference->m.' months, ' 
                   .$difference->d.' days';

print_r($difference);
```

But it's returns wrong days in following output

```
Difference: 0 years, 4 months, 120 daysDateInterval Object
(
    [y] = 0
    [m] = 4
    [d] = 0
    [h] = 0
    [i] = 0
    [s] = 0
    [invert] = 0
    [days] = 120
)
```

Why this given wrong output of days ?

Comment: Is the date in your database stored as a string, or in a `Date`/`timestamp` column?

Comment: The reason for your issue is that you're not using a proper date format (see Maxim's answer below for how to create a DateTime object from that format). You should always store your date-information in a `date` or `timestamp` column, makes handling dates *so much easier*.

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain and store dates using a correct date data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use 'd/m/Y' format you should use `createFromFormat` function to convert string date to date object. For example:

```
$date1 = new \DateTime();
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '05/03/2019');

$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Comment: attach your date from `$date1` variable, please

Comment: Yes, It's working actually it's takes melbourne time and i checked in IST but finally it's work. Thanks a lot!! :)